# Who do I install PHP Blenc on Ubuntu 14?

Tags: php, encryption

What is the easiest way to install PHP Blenc on Ubuntu 14?

Answer (score 2):

@the_seppi answer is good and detailed and will probably do you, but I would like too add The quick way,using a terminal

```
sudo -i
apt-get install php5-dev build-essential
apt-get install php-pear
pecl download channel://pecl.php.net/blenc-1.1.4b
tar xzf blenc-1.1.4b.tgz
cd blenc-1.1.4b
phpize
```

Before you launch the configuration script you can change hardcoded key and expiration date in the `blenc_protect.h` file. Follow instruction in that file in order to edit information. Save changes and launch the configure script.

```
./configure 
make 
make install
```

Now you have to edit your `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` configuration, adding at the end of file directives to load BLENC extension.

```
; BLENC PHP Extension
extension=blenc.so
```

[Here is my source](http://giuseppechiesa.it/_dropplets/php-blenc-quick-start-guide) with more details on further features

Answer (score 1):

From http://php.net/manual/en/intro.blenc.php, just to have said it:

> **Warning** This extension is *EXPERIMENTAL*. The behaviour of this extension including the names of its functions and any other documentation surrounding this extension may change without notice in a future release of PHP. This extension should be used at your own risk.

---

First, of course, you need PHP to be installed. I'll assume you already did this. Now, the guys from BLENC recommend **not** to use the easy method, so I'll skip that:

> It's strongly recommended to install BLENC from sources without 'pecl' command. In this way you can:
>
> - Specify your personal encryption key used to create redistributable keys. Your sourcecode will be more difficult to decrypt also for users that can read your key_file on webserver.
> - Specify a expiration date for the BLENC module. With expiration date you can decide that BLENC module on target system will work until a date. After that BLENC will not decrypt any files.
>
> All these configuration options are stored into header file: blenc_protect.h
>   Please read the content of blenc_protect.h in sources of BLENC to know how set these hardcoded options.

The 'hard way' (and recommended one) is to build the extension from source:

1. Install the *php5-dev* package: `sudo apt-get install php5-dev`
2. Download BLENC's source from [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/BLENC)
3. Extract the downloaded archive, open a terminal and `cd` into the directory with the extracted files
4. Run the following commands, as from [this instruction](http://php.net/manual/de/install.pecl.phpize.php). Before you do so, heed the recommendation from the authors and have a look at `blenc_protect.h` and do whatever it says in there, if you wish to do so.

   ```
   phpize
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
5. The compiled module will automatically be moved to the correct directory. All left to do is to activate it by adding

   ```
   extension=php_blenc.so
   ```

   to your `php.ini` file. I think you'll notice in case the actual name is different. The default setup should now be concluded.